# Why can't I use the string ID android.R.string.share?

Tags: android, android-resources

It's right there in values/strings.xml in Android's source - why isn't it in android.R?

**edit**: I am referring to Android's built in string resources (`android.R.string.…`) and not my own project's resources - so, for example, while I can use `android.R.string.cancel`, I can't use `android.R.string.share` despite the fact that the two of them are declared in the same file in Android's source code

Comment: Not all resources are public and thats why you can't access share.

Answer (score 1):

They are just resources under the resource folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string name="share">hello</string>
</resources>
```

The above resource has a entry in R.java file which in under your package name. You can open R.java and have a look at it.

```
    public static final int share=0x7f040000;
```

You can refer to the string in Strings.xml as

```
  R.String.share
```

The R.strin.share is an int.

You can also get the string as

```
   String s= getResources().getString(R.string.share);
```

Edit:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html#PlatformResources.

Check the topic in the above link under the heading **Accessing Platform Resources**

Android contains a number of standard resources, such as styles, themes, and layouts. To access these resource, qualify your resource reference with the android package name.

For list of all resources check the link

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.html

The list from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.string.html

[image]

Comment: You should use R thats under you project package name. Why would you refer to resources under system?

Comment: because some strings are just very common - for example "Cancel" - it's already translated to hundreds of languages in Android, why would I want recreated that when I can just build on their work? Same with icons, I'm using android.R.drawable.ic_menu_share, this way my app always uses the current platform's share icon :)

Comment: check the dit. You can refer to the system resources using android package name.

Comment: that's what I've been trying to do - but android.R.string.share doesn't exist (despite the fact that a "share" string element is defined in strings.xml in the Android source code)

Comment: @daniel i checked i din't see share. I could see copy cancel and so on.. but no share. Cross check again. I could refer as android.R.string.cancel. Check the link for the list http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.string.html

Comment: It's right there, alongside "cancel" (which I can use) - https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/ics-mr0/core/res/res/values/strings.xml#L3098 (this is the branch for ICS, my minimum API version - it's also in all API version above that and in the master branch)

Comment: I understand that there's a limited list, from strings.xml, that I can use - my original questions is *why* can't I use the other strings

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.string.html. I don't see share according to the documentation on the developer site. i do not know  about the code in github. You can ask the author who posted it.

Comment: @daniel you should ask this question to the google android developer's. They cam answer this. But According to the documentation you can access those in the link i mentioned. May its not public so you can't have access to share. May be for security reasons.

Comment: @daniel i too checked the strings.xml from the sdk. Share is present in strings.xml along with bunch of other stuffs. I think it is bcoz of security you can't access all of them. You can sent a mail to security@android.com. The security team may be able to answer your question

Answer (score 1):

You are compiling for which SDK version??
Please check strings.xml of same SDK version..I think there is some mismatch in target SDK version and strings.xml(you are referring to, where "share" is present)

However i will recommend to add your own "share" string in application strings.xml, to avoid unwanted issues due to Android Fragmented nature.

Comment: he wants to access system string resources. I don' tthink there is any issue with the sdk version

Comment: i am also talking about system String resources, as each SDK version will have its own set of resources, so my doubt is daniel is seeing some other SDK version strings.xml(different from app target sdk)

Comment: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/ics-mr0/core/res/res/values/strings.xml#L3098. From this link for ics.  Share does exist in android api 16 coz i have android api 16 and i cross checked the same. You check the comment made by daniel below my answer. He says its above all versions mentioned in the link

Answer (score 0):

android.R is the system's R

Your R is just R within your own package name. So just call it `R.string.share` instead of `android.R.string.share` when referring to it.

Comment: The system's R will vary depending on which api level you're using. That's why it's not recommended to use the system's R for that kind of thing. Use your own R for strings. Your app will be more portable that way.

Comment: Luckily for us there's LINT to warn us when API versions break - R is just like any other API as far as I'm concerned, I assume it won't just stop working (it might be marked as deprecated, but that's different)

Comment: Yes, it works just like with the other internal code apis. If you found an api in the source itself, but that api is not publicly documented. You can assume that this internal api may get changed in the future by Google, or by any of the numerous OEMs, since that api also probably won't be documented under the Compatibility Test Suite (that OEMs have to comply with). That's what undocumented apis are. The rule of thumb is not to use them. No one has promised you that they will keep on working. In fact, Google only keeps on saying to developers that it's a mistake to try to use them.

Answer (score 0):

It's because it is not defined in android.R.string, but in com.android.internal.R$string. you cannot access it without some 'hack'.

```
   public static int getReflactField(String className,String fieldName){
       int result = 0;
       try {
           Class<?> clz = Class.forName(className);
           Field field = clz.getField(fieldName);
           field.setAccessible(true);
           result = field.getInt(null); 
       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       return result;
   }
   ...
   int share_id=getReflactField("com.android.internal.R$string", "share");
   if(share_id!=0)
       Toast.makeText(getContext(), ""+getResources().getString(share_id),0).show();
```

this works both on my android 4.4 and 8.0 device

Or simply use
`getResources().getString(Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("share","string", "android"))`